# testing popstate event with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (paymentSuccessful)
      window.addEventListener('popstate', handleBrowserBtn);
    return () => 
window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleBrowserBtn);
  }, [paymentSuccessful]);
```

`handleBrowserBtn` is a function that gets called when user clicks on the browser back button. I'm trying to test this using Jest, but I'm unable to trigger the `window.addEventListener('popstate')`. Please let me know if there is any way to simulate this using Jest.

Comment: What is your question? This is not clear at all (even the title has spelling errors). Please try to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate this in jest . but i'm not able to . I need to simulate browser back button action

Comment: edited the question to the best i could. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Since window is global object, so in our test, we can mock implement the addEventListener and then try invoking the second argument of that mock function.

```
const mockAddEventListener = jest.fn();
  window.addEventListener = mockAddEventListener;
  // do your action here which will trigger useEffect

  // here the first [0] of calls denotes the first call of the mock
  // the second [0] denotes the index of arguments passed to that call
  expect(mockAddEventListener.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('popstate');

  // so we can trigger handleBrowserBtn by calling [1] index
  mockAddEventListener.mock.calls[0][1]();

// now assert here what was being done in handleBrowserBtn callback
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Hi Anuradha. Thanks for the reply. when I tried this, i'm getting the following error. 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: Did you do the action so that useEffect gets called after mocking the event listener? And also the payment Successful flag should be true for the call to invoke